# How to get the Past Due Amount and Current Due Amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables namely Loans and Payments. I have no problem in extracting the total dues with this script:

```
SELECT SUM(x.Principal) - sum(amount_paid) 
FROM Payments
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(Principal) as Principal 
             FROM Loans 
             WHERE AmortizationDate <= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) 
               AND AccountNo = 2020001) AS x  
WHERE date_paid <= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) 
  AND AccountNo =  = 2020001
```

but I would like to determine the overdue amount (past due) and current due amount.

Loans:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Loans]
(  
    [RecID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [LoanApplicationId] [bigint] NULL,  
    [AccountNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,  
    [LoanAmount] [decimal](16, 2) NULL,  
    [AmortizationDate] [date] NULL,  
    [Principal] [decimal](16, 2) NULL,  
CONSTRAINT [PK_Loans] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
( 
    [RecID] ASC  
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,   
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]  
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Payments:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Payments]
(
    [RecID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [receipt_no] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL, 
    [AccountNo] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL, 
    [date_paid] [datetime] NULL,
    [amount_paid] [money] NULL, 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Payments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
( 
    [RecID] ASC 
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,  
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample Loans Data:

```
INSERT INTO Loans
           ([LoanApplicationId]
           ,[AccountNo]
           ,[LoanAmount]
           ,[AmortizationDate]
           ,[Principal])
     VALUES
           (2
           ,2020001
           ,310000.00
           ,'1/30/2019'
           ,103333.33
          )  
INSERT INTO Loans
           ([LoanApplicationId]
           ,[AccountNo]
           ,[LoanAmount]
           ,[AmortizationDate]
           ,[Principal])
     VALUES
           (2
           ,2020001
           ,310000.00
           ,'2/28/2020'
           ,103333.33
          )  
INSERT INTO Loans
           ([LoanApplicationId]
           ,[AccountNo]
           ,[LoanAmount]
           ,[AmortizationDate]
           ,[Principal])
     VALUES
           (2
           ,2020001
           ,310000.00
           ,'3/31/2020'
           ,103333.33
          )
```

Sample Payments Data:

```
 INSERT INTO Payments
               ([receipt_no]
               ,[AccountNo]
               ,[date_paid]
               ,[amount_paid])
         VALUES
               (1
               ,2020001
               ,'1/30/2020'
               ,103333.33)
```

I would like to generate something like this:

Case 1: 
If accountee is not able to pay on 2/28/2020 due date and reached 3/31/2020, his overdue account is 103, 333.33 while current due is 103, 333.33.

Case 2: 
If accountee can pay on 2/28/2020 half amount on his due date and reached 3/31/2020, his overdue account is 51,666.665 while current due is 103, 333.33.

Case 3: 
If accountee can pay on 2/28/2020 on his due date with advance payment and reached 3/31/2020, his overdue account is 103, 333.33 while current due is 51,666.66.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
    declare @dueamount money,@overdueamount money

    set @dueamount=

    (
    (select sum(principal)
    from
    (select  *
     from #loans
    where AmortizationDate<getdate()
    union
    select  
    top 1 * from #loans
    where AmortizationDate>getdate())A)
    -
    (select sum(amount_paid) from #Payments))




    set @overdueamount=
    (
    (
    select  SUM(Principal)
     from #loans
    where AmortizationDate<getdate()
    )
    -
    (select sum(amount_paid) from #Payments))

    select @dueamount as [Due Amount], @overdueamount as [OverDue Amount]
```

Comment: I tried it using the different cases i mentioned. To try the second case mentioned above,  I used following data:

Comment: where are you getting problem?

Comment: For Test Case 1: <br>
Due Date: 3/31/2020 <br>
Expected result was displayed. <br>
However, if accountee decided to inquire ealier about his dues, let say 3/15/2020, it displays the following result.

Due Amount: 206666.66
OverDue Amount: 103333.33

Comment: For Test Case 2: It results to <br/> 
Due Amount: 51,666.67 <br> 
OverDue Amount: 51,666.67  <br> 
which should be
Due Amount: 103333.33 <br> 
OverDue Amount: 51,666.67  <br>

Comment: For Test Case 3: It results to <br> 
Due Amount: -51666.66<br> 
OverDue Amount: -51666.66<br> 
which should be
Due Amount: 51,666.67 <br> 
OverDue Amount: 0.00 <br>